# Permissions error while appending to Excel file with Pandas ExcelWriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, io

While writing results of my script to an Excel file, it seems that pd.ExcelWriter can't open the file in "Append" mode properly. Every time I try, I face

```py
Permissions Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

However, if I overwrite the original file and open initially in "Write" mode, it will delete the old contents, and any subsequent attempts to open the file in "Append" mode succeed without raising a Permissions Error.

I have checked the file permissions on all of the directories and the file itself, and all are owned by my user account with read and write privileges instated. I am on MacOS 10.15.7, using `openpyxl` as the ExcelWriter engine. If anyone understands why ExcelWriter has trouble opening the file properly, please let me know. Maybe it's an issue of opening the file prior to using an ExcelWriter instance on it? I will try and update this post with my attempt.

The code for the I/O is:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/file.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    dataFrame.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheetname='Name_of_run')
    #and just for security, even though I have confirmed that using writer
    #in a with clause will save and close it properly
    writer.save()
```

Edit:
I tried to open the file normally through Python's `open` function, and I received the same permissions error. Again, I have checked all of the file and directory permissions and all are properly assigned.

Comment: That depends a lot on your code. Without the code, we can't really say much. What I imagine is you append in a loop and forgot to close the file instance.

Comment: No, I made sure to open the ExcelWriter instance inside of a ```with``` clause so that it will close automatically. Like I said, the first instance opening the file is the one that causes the issue, if I choose to overwrite and erase the original file the remaining append attempts succeed.

Comment: @QuangHoang I added an example of the code that is causing the error